# Problemas con existencia de usuario en node.js/angular

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0

Buen dia comunidad, Tengo una duda, tengo un formulario de editar, pero en el backend tengo un metodo de que si el email ya existe, no pueda editar el formulario, el problema es que en angular los input me aparecen rellenos con los datos, y si cambio todo menos el email, no me deja porque me envia la informacion del input email, como haria para que me envie la informacion del input de email solamente si escribo sobre el, he intentado con dirty pero me da undefined porque creo que la informacion desde el backend ya viene asi, creo que el problema viene siendo desde node.js. dejo el codigo de la validacion de email de node.js.

```
  function updateUser(req, res) {
  var userId = req.params.id;
  var params = req.body;
  var user = new User();
  user.email = params.email;
  if (userId != req.user.sub) {
    return res.send({ message: 'No tienes permisos' });
  }
  User.find({ email: params.email.toLowerCase() }, (err, docs) => {
    if (!docs.length) {
      User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, params, (err, userUpdated) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error updating the user' 
});
        } else {
          if (!userUpdated) {
            res.status(404).send({ message: "The user can't be update" });
          } else {
            res.status(200).send({ user: userUpdated });
          }
        }
      });
     } else {
       res.json({ msg: 'El email ya ha sido elegido por otra persona' 
 });
}
  });
}
```

Aqui esta el update.ts de angular

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { User } from '../../user';
    import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
    import { GLOBAL } from '../../../global';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-update-user',
      templateUrl: './update-user.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./update-user.component.scss']
    })
    export class UpdateUserComponent implements OnInit {
      public rForm: FormGroup;
      public user: User;
      public identity;
      public token;
      public url: string;
      public alertMessage: string;
      public filesToUpload: Array<File>;

      constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private fb: FormBuilder
      ) {
        this.url = GLOBAL.url;

        this.rForm = fb.group({
          update: fb.group({
            name: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            lastname: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
            email: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.email])]
          })
        });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.identity = this.authService.getIdentity();
        this.token = this.authService.getToken();
        this.user = this.identity;
      }

      fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
        this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>>fileInput.target.files;
      }

      onSubmit() {
        this.authService.updateUser(this.user).subscribe(
          response => {
            if (!response.user) {
              console.log(response.user);
              this.alertMessage = 'El usuario no se ha actualizado';
            } else {
              console.log('desde el this.user' + this.user.name);
              console.log('desde el response.user' + response.user.name);
              localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.user));

              let identity = this.user;
              this.identity = identity;
              this.authService.sendIden(this.identity);
              if (!this.filesToUpload) {
              } else {
                this.makeFileRequest(
                  this.url + 'imagen-usuario/' + this.user._id,
                  [],
                  this.filesToUpload
                ).then((result: any) => {
                  this.user.image = result.image;
                  localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.user));
                  let image_path = this.url + 'ver-imagen/' + this.user.image;
                });
              }
              this.alertMessage = 'El usuario se ha actualizado';
              this.authService.sendIden(this.identity);
            }
          },
          error => {
            var alertMessage = <any>error;
            if (alertMessage != null) {
              var body = JSON.parse(error._body);
              this.alertMessage = body.message;
            }
          }
        );
      }
```

Y aqui esta el Update.html

```
<div *ngIf="identity">
      {{alertMessage}}
      <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div formGroupName="update">
          <label>Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
          <label>Apellido</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="lastname" [(ngModel)]="user.lastname">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email">
          <div class="image_for_edit">
            <img src= '{{url+"ver-imagen/"+user.image}}' style="width: 50px;" alt="">
            <p>

              <label >Upload your avatar</label>
              <input type="file" placegolder="Upload image..."(change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

          <input type="submit"  value="Actualizar informacion" [disabled]="rForm.invalid">   
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Deberías poner el código de lo que haces en el cliente. Con eso no me queda claro que está pasando en el navegador.

Comment: Básicamente en el evento `change` del input email coloca un listener que haga una consulta al backend para ver si el email existe; en este caso podrías desactivar el botón de envío para hacerlo mucho más realtime y mostrar el mensaje de error debajo del input email.

Comment: El problema es que si el no coloca nada, aun aparece el correo anteriormente ya colocado y cuando haga el evento y busque en la base de datos, pensara que el correo esta repetido porque esta escrito en el input y no me dejara enviar la informacion. Necesito una forma de no enviar la informacion del correo si no la modifico, de verdad no logro dar con la solucion, ya subi update.html y el update.ts